# How to make two-directional unix domain sockets with SOCK_DGRAM?

Tags: c, network-programming, datagram, unix-socket, socat

I am trying to write a simple Unix datagram server/client, and am having some problems. What I want is a server that listens on a datagram socket and sends a reply to every message received, to the original sender. I decided to try first using `socat` to be the "server" and writing the client in C. I am running socat like this:

```
socat UNIX-DGRAM:/tmp/test.socket,fork EXEC:echo
```

To the best of my understanding this should listen on `/tmp/test.socket` and reply to everything that is received with the same string? Then I have a client program that looks like this (error checking removed for clarity):

```
int s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_un sa;
sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(sa.sun_path, "/tmp/test.socket");

const char *data = "Testing data";
int err = sendto(s, data, strlen(data), 0, (struct sockaddr *)(&sa), sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

printf("Sent!\n");

unsigned char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH);
struct sockaddr_storage recv_sa;
int recv_sa_len = 0;
int recv_len = recvfrom(s, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_sa, &recv_sa_len);

for (int i = 0; i < recv_len; i++) {
    putc(buffer[i], stdout);
}
printf("\n");
```

It should send the packet (that works), receive a packet, and then print it out, but the program doesn't seem to be capable of receiving the packet. What am I doing wrong here, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding about Unix sockets? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the Michael Kerrisk's AF_UNIX SOCK_DGRAM example of the  client/server program ([client](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/ud_ucase_cl.c.html), [server](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/ud_ucase_sv.c.html)) published in his book The Linux Programming Interface, chapter 57.

Comment: I don't consider a raw reference as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Socket need to have address to be addressed to receive packets. You can call `bind()` with unique socket filename based on the PID or in linux use autobound abstract address if to call before `send`:

```
bind(s, (const struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa_family_t));
```

Answer (score -3):

You should call *connect* before of trying send nothing to the echo server.

Take a look at: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html

Comment: Is is the case that, since I am using a datagram socket (not SOCK_STREAM), it should function kind of like UDP where I can send datagrams anywhere I like without having to connect first? Like I mentioned, the part where the client sends to the server does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: Clearly says datagram, yet you suggest connecting. Any reason?