# How to build an echo server and client using asio local datagram?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

// server

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    ::unlink("local_socket");
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint endpoint("local_socket");
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket socket(io_service, endpoint);

    char recv_buf[1024];
    while (1)
    {
        boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint senderEndpoint;
        size_t len = socket.receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf, 1024), senderEndpoint);
        printf("***%s###\n", senderEndpoint.path().c_str());

        socket.send_to(
            boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf, len), senderEndpoint);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

// client

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint endpoint("local_socket");
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.open();

    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request);

    socket.send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length), endpoint);

    char reply[max_length];
    size_t reply_length = socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(reply, max_length), endpoint);

    std::cout << "Reply is: ";
    std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I use client to send "123", and server is coredump with:

> ***### terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  send_to: Invalid argument Aborted

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325468/how-to-make-two-directional-unix-domain-sockets-with-sock-dgram).
[client](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/ud_ucase_cl.c.html),[server](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/ud_ucase_sv.c.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the server aborting is because the `senderEndpoint` is not being populated by the call to `receive_from` - the client socket is not bound to anything so it does not send a file descriptor on which to receive responses. If we refactor the client like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

enum { max_length = 1024 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint server_endpoint("local_socket");
    // Create client endpoint on which to receive response
    std::string client_addr = "local_socket.";
    client_addr += std::to_string(::getpid());
    ::unlink(client_addr.c_str());
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint client_endpoint(client_addr.c_str());
    boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket socket(io_service, client_endpoint);

    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request);

    socket.send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length), server_endpoint);

    char reply[max_length];
    size_t reply_length = socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(reply, max_length), client_endpoint);

    std::cout << "Reply is: ";
    std::cout.write(reply, reply_length);
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

then it works as expected:

```
Enter message: 123
***local_socket.29635###
Reply is: 123
```